# Min IO. Problem with adding data to Min IO

Tags: java, minio

I'm using latest Min IO docker image and latest version of Min IO.
There is no problem with fetching data from buckets but upload or put methods doesn't work for me.
Next part of code

`minioClient.putObject(PutObjectArgs.builder() .contentType(contentType) .stream(inputStream, -1, 5242881) .bucket(bucket) .object(objectName) .build());`

Is throwing error like this

`io.minio.errors.ErrorResponseException: Invalid Request (request has multiple authentication types, please use one) at io.minio.S3Base$1.onResponse(S3Base.java:690)`

I tried to make bucket public and create new user with admin like access rules